# How to make a rails app "portable"?

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that needs a lot of initial data. This data includes default configuration preferences, states information and some company information. This information is not gonna change, but I have it in the database because is huge.

The problem here is that the application won't work without that data. So, how can I make this info easily loaded into the database when I change environments from dev to test/prod and when I deploy the app to the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the database, maybe is useful to create a .rb file with your initial info or configuration, and add this file to be loaded at the beginning of your config/initializers folder. Everything added here with be loaded by the boot.rb file.

Hope it helps.

PD: I'm supposing you're using rails 2.3 and above. (minus rails 3 and above).